# Is is good or bad to have the email address of a domain's registrant on the same domain?

Tags: dns, domain-registration, godaddy, domain-registrar, email-address

Say I own domain abc.com.

I think it's a bad idea to use eric@abc.com as the registrant's (myself) email address.
This will cause problems when I need to transfer the domain to another registrar e.g. GoDaddy. The new registrar will then try to send email to eric@abc.com which is unlikely to function normally since the DNS settings are undergoing changes.

So I believe it's best to use email address independent from the domains I own as the registrant's email address. (Isn't it the practice Google Apps is using?)

Have I missed something here or am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose another, independent, address you will have no potential loss or notification problem (1) when the new domain is set up or (2) when you transfer the domain. Some registrars / hosters also explicitly recommend it that way.